# iphone view based application without reloading views

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am building view based application,which has many pages an  in every page ther will be home button,which will call homepage but my problem is whenever i call home page the view will reload but i dont need to reload so please suggest me....

HomePage.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    twitAll=0;
    facAll=0;
    CrtPage=0;
    flag=[[NSString alloc]init];
    [self Maintainpages];
    [tbv setFrame:CGRectMake(0*self.scrollView.frame.size.width,0,self.scrollView.frame.size.width,self.scrollView.frame.size.height-90)];
    [tbv1 setFrame:CGRectMake(1*self.scrollView.frame.size.width,0,self.scrollView.frame.size.width,self.scrollView.frame.size.height-90)];
    [tbv2 setFrame:CGRectMake(2*self.scrollView.frame.size.width,0,self.scrollView.frame.size.width,self.scrollView.frame.size.height-90)];
    [tbv3 setFrame:CGRectMake(3*self.scrollView.frame.size.width,0,self.scrollView.frame.size.width,self.scrollView.frame.size.height-90)];
    tbv1.hidden=YES;
    tbv2.hidden=YES;
    tbv3.hidden=YES;
    tbv.hidden=YES;
    self.view.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Background-bluegray.png"]];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(LoginCompletedSuccess:) name:@"IntigrateCompleted" object:nil];
    topbar.backgroundColor=[[[UIColor alloc]initWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"top-bar.png"]]autorelease];
    bottombar.backgroundColor=[[[UIColor alloc]initWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"top-bar.png"]]autorelease];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For not reloading the view you should add all newView as subview of the parent view with this source code.

```
[parentView addSubview:childView];
```

and bring this subView to front

```
[parentView bringSubviewToFront:childView];
```

On click the home button remove all subView's and it will should you the parentView

```
for(UIView *subview in [parentView subviews]) {
    [subview removeFromSuperview];
}
```